Date set in parameter does not match with date when querying the parameter

As you can see in the screenshot I set a parameter with datatype date and selected the date 2024-05-27.
However, when I query this parameter in SQL, I am getting a completely different value (1992-01-01).
Do you know why this is the case and how to solve it?

What is the raw data for start_date, and what is the type of that column?

raw data is the selected parameter (on the left side of the flash sign in the screenshot)

You've set the parameter to the arithmetic expression 2024 minus 05 minus 27 (The result of which is 1992) but you should be using the STRING '2024-05-27'

The thing you need to do to get this parameter is:
SELECT '{{start_date}}'

Then you can cast it to date with:
SELECT TO_DATE('{{start_date}}')

